# Can I use primers from different paint companies in the same room?

Tags: paint

I have two partial cans of older primer along with a full can of new primer. I'm going to paint a room. Can I use all of the primer cans for the project, or should I only use the same primer throughout?

Comment: Why are you priming? Is it fresh drywall/plaster, or unpainted wood? Is there a lot of repair work to cover?

Comment: @JimmyFix-it, I'm priming an already-painted bedroom. It's a 1940s house and the walls are plaster.

Comment: Okay, **you don't need primer** (unless you have some problem surface); use high-quality paint and professional grade applicators, 2 coats and done. Pay zero attention to those that tell you different (especially those that *sell* primer).

Comment: What about when the current paint is much darker than the new paint? That's the case here.

Comment: @ndronen, I used to believe that primer was to "hide" the color below. From reading on the Internet I have recently come to very different understanding. Primer is used when the paint does not adhere properly to the surface below, or if the surface has other problems like being too pourous. When the paint is somehow incompatible with the surface, primer is a buffer between the surface and the paint. It sounds like you dont need primer. Disclaimer: im not a professional.

Answer (score 0):

### If it's latex primer, watch the smell - or just throw it out.

Especially now with the low-VOC regulations, mold or fungus can get growing in a can of water-based paint or primer. It creates a horrible smell (but one easily attributed to "the expected stink of paint".

**You don't find out until after you've painted a wall that the smell isn't leaving. Ever.**  It will then defy every possible effort to seal it in, cover it up, etc.  Now you have to remove it all. What a job!  These nightmares *have* ended with people having to tear the drywall off the wall.

### Primer's job is to create a uniform surface

So that the topcoat will behave the same all over the room - be an equally appropriate surface for paint, absorb the same, sheen the same, and have its color print through the same.  Otherwise if you painted a checkerboard wall, the checkerboard would still be printing through after 2-3 topcoats.

So you want to arrange the primer job so that the final *primer* coat is essentially the same throughout the room.  Whatever sequence of use makes that work best, that's what you do.   If the characteristics of the three products are similar enough, that may be enough.

### Mix products together? Not without factory consultation

Because even if they are the same type (alkyd vs latex) they may not be compatible chemically.

Comment: If you paint a checkerboard wall with three coats of Farrow and Ball topcoat it won't show through.  Also Claypaint.  (But those are very high-end paints, it's a lot cheaper to use primer and only need one or two coats.)

Comment: @MartinBonner depends on the hue.  I've had to use 4 coats of yellow just to cover a gray primer.  Works better with white and better still with 80/20 white/gray primer.

Comment: I mean in that particular case, it was exterior work, and I was using $300/gal marine paint with the best pigments money can buy (and it's slim pickings for yellow, since lead chromate has been outlawed).  Different deal in interior, where you have far, far less UV light and can get away with affordable organic pigments.